# Provide a condensed structure for the following compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, lewis-structure

[image: This is the structure that I'm trying to write in condensed form.]

I keep getting, (CH3)3CCH2CH2CHNH2CHCHCH3. However, the homework system keeps counting it as incorrect, and I don't know what part is incorrect. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, i can see at least one other option, but as yours is also correct, that's rather exercise in futility.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing a set of parentheses. For compounds like this, the NH2 group should be in parentheses to show that it is not part of the chain.

[image]

$\ce{(CH3)3CCH2CH2CH(NH2)CHCHCH3}$.

However, Mithoron's comment makes a valid point. There are lots of ways to do this. If your homework system only codes one as correct, then that is frustrating. Better to talk to your instructor about the specific question.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried the parentheses and it still marked it wrong. I'll go ask my instructor on Monday.